# I want to create a vba userform in excel for my personal calculations. But I'm having trouble using it

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Help me I need to create a Userform for my personal calculations. But I ran into a lot of problems. Because I've never written a program before.
When I enter a value 0 or enter a value other than 0 and delete it in the text field PriceCoinBuy, BuyCoin , PriceCoinSell , SellCoin , Vat one of the fields I will get Msg : Run-time error '6'; overflow.
But when I put a number other than 0 in the BuyCoin field, I get Msg : Run-time error '11'; Division by zero.
I've been searching for a solution for 2 days but can't find it in please help.
I have 5 textboxes for input.

> ```
> Sub SumAll()
>  
>  Dim A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, V As Double
>
>  
>  A = Val(Order.PriceCoinBuy.Value)
>  B = Val(Order.BuyCoin.Value)
>  C = Val(Order.PriceCoinSell.Value)
>  D = Val(Order.SellCoin.Value)
>  V = Val(Order.Vat.Value)
>  
>  '-------------- Math --------------
>  E = CDbl(B) / A
>  F = CDbl(E) * (V / 100)
>  
>  G = CDbl(E) - F
>  H = CDbl(G) * A
>  
>  I = CDbl(D) * C
>  J = CDbl(I) * (V / 100)
>  K = CDbl(I) - J
>  
>  '---------------- Show -------------
>  Order.GetCoin.Text = Format(E, "##,##0.000000")
>  Order.AfterVatBuy.Text = Format(F, "##,##0.0000")
>  Order.CoinBalance.Text = Format(G, "##,##0.000000")
>  Order.ToMoney.Text = Format(H, "##,##0.00")
>  
>  Order.GetMoney.Text = Format(I, "##,##0.00")
>  Order.AfterVatSell.Text = Format(J, "##,##0.00")
>  Order.MoneyBalance.Text = Format(K, "##,##0.00")
>  
> End Sub
> ```

Comment: Hi. In line `Dim A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, V As Double`, only V is typed, the other variables are Variant. I suppose `Order` is the form? You know that variables can have names longer than one letter, do you? Where do you call the sub from?

Comment: Yes, order are forms , I know that variables can have names longer than one letter.